# Kernel panic Ubuntu 20.04 and initramfs unpacking failed

Tags: dual-boot

I get this error when trying to start my computer:

[image: kernel panic]

I found a way to enter in a previous version of kernel (5.4.0-42) but when the computer reboots I'm still getting the same message. I'm new in Ubuntu so I really don't know what to do.

UPDATE

[image]

[image]

Here is the disk test!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a corrupt ramdisk file.

If you can boot into Recovery Mode/Root Access, in your most current kernel, type:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`

If you can't boot into Recovery Mode, boot to the 5.4.0-42 kernel version, then:

`ls -al /boot`

You'll see something similar to this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237769 Aug 26 06:15 config-5.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237769 Sep  4 12:08 config-5.4.0-47-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     1024 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep 16 14:21 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Sep 13 18:27 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 49932343 Sep  4 14:34 initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 49932783 Sep 16 14:21 initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Sep 13 18:27 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18 03:46 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18 03:46 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18 03:46 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4740251 Aug 26 06:15 System.map-5.4.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4740251 Sep  4 12:08 System.map-5.4.0-47-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Sep 13 18:27 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11670272 Aug 26 06:19 vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11670272 Sep  4 12:18 vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Sep 13 18:27 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic
```

Note that in my example, my most current linux kernel version is `5.4.0-47-generic`.

Now type this command:

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-47-generic`

replacing `5.4.0-47-generic` with your most current (failing) version.

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

Let's check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

<strike>- type `reboot`</strike>

Let's check your disk SMART status...

Open the `Disks` application. Select your disk in the left pane. Go to the "hamburger" icon, and select **SMART Data & Tests**. Take screenshot(s) of the scrollable data window and [edit them into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1277183/edit).

**Update #2:**

Time to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Did exactly that in the 5.4.0-42 version, couldn’t get in the recovery mode for the most recent, and now i can’t boot in neither, not even in recovery mode

Comment: @Lonsotibas  I'm sorry to hear about your problem. I didn't want you to do that for the -42 version, but rather for the failing kernel version. Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: dont worry thanks for helping me, i already update the post

Comment: @Lonsotibas How did the `fsck` part go?

Comment: no errors when i execute it, but still can not boot

Comment: @Lonsotibas Time to reinstall Ubuntu. If the installer gives you the opportunity, uncheck the **Format** option, and it should leave your /home folder alone. If you don't have good backups, boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and drag off your files to another attached USB disk/flash first.

Comment: I supposed this could happen, luckily i have backup, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Lonsotibas Are you running with a new Ubuntu install now?

Comment: For reference, just had this problem on Ubuntu 22.02 LTS and this solution works. I am unable to boot using the latest kernal in safe mode, but able to boot in a previous version  kernal.

Comment: @cytsunny Check to make sure that you have the latest BIOS for your computer.